# How to get parameter which is containing question mark(?) from rest url in spring

Tags: java, rest, url

i need get string from url where is "?" but controller does not accept "?"

I need send something like "Hello world?"
but I get only "Hello world"

I find solution for dot(.) -- value = "{textToTransform:.+}"

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(textTransformCtrl.BASE_URI)
public class textTransformCtrl {

    @Autowired
    private TextTransformatorService textTransformatorService;

    public static final String BASE_URI = "transform/text";

    @RequestMapping(value = "{textToTransform:.+}")
    public String getText(@PathVariable final String textToTransform) {

        return textTransformatorService.transformText(textToTransform);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Question mark is a reserved character in URLs. It indicates where the *query string* starts.

If you want to send a `?` as a parameter value and be able to read it on server side, you must URL encode it.

When URL encoded, `Hello world?` becomes `Hello+world%3F`.

Comment: Not as a parameter. It becomes `Hello+World%3F`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%3F` to manually encode it or take a look at [UriBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html)